# Decline job offer when using recruiter

Tags: recruitment, job-offer

I received a job offer which I want to decline, the recruiter went above and beyond to negotiate the salary, considering I had an offer elsewhere but told them I preferred their role, but at the end I have decided to go with the other offer. I have not told them I accepted the other offer. The recruiter now wants to meet face to face to talk about the offer, how do decline politely and still stay in contact for future roles.

Answer (score 0):

Decline the offer quickly and politely, and tell them why you picked the other position. Unless their negotiated offer met all your stated criteria they knew there was a risk you would decline the offer.

The recruiter is probably not that interested in maintaining a continuous relationship with you. They tried to fit you into an open position and was unable to do so. One of the following things happened or will happen: the company went with another of their candidates; the company went with a candidate represented by another recruiter; or the position remains unfilled.

Rejecting an offer to stay in your current job means they may be able to convince you next time; moving to another company may take you off the market for years.

If your new position fits you well, and you perform well, and the new company survives you will be off the market for years. They may keep you in their database to passively send you open positions, or they may add you to a tickler file to contact you in 6 months to see if you are open to moving again.

You can always reach out to then if you ever want to leave the new company.